# clrscr(); equivalent in Code::Blocks

Tags: c++, codeblocks

how to clear the output console in code blocks?? 
why doesn't clrscr();  work in Code::Blocks but works in Borland??

I have already tried:

```
cout << "\x1b[2J\x1b[1;1H" << flush;
cls() ;
```

Comment: Did you `#include <conio.h>`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The easiest most straightforward way is to just do it through `system` function call:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  system("cls");
}
```

If you want to do it programmatically **[MSDN shows how here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/99261)**.

Note that there is no standard function provided by C++ for clearing the console. Some compilers, like borland, provides it as a non-standard function for convenience but it's not portable between different compilers.

Comment: and BTW does "system("cls");" work on every c/c++ IDE and Compiler??

Comment: @gandalf `system` itself is a standard function provided by `stdlib.h`. However, the command you pass to it will be platform dependent. For example, on linux you would do `system("clear")` or `system("reset")` instead.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually a quite simple problem.
All you have to do is use printf.
You don't even need printf or any headers, for that matter.

```
printf("\e[1;1H\e[2J");
```

The \e[1;1H sets the screen to the 1st row and 1st column. the 2J overwrites all characters currently on the screen.

You can also use this:

```
write(0,"\e[1;1H\e[2J",12);
```

Then you don't need stdio.h.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the OS commands to clear the contents of the console.

```
#include<stdlib.h>
int main(){

system("cls");   //For windows
system("clear"); //For Linux

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create own function in own header file which contain clrscr() and use it.
for example :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
void clrscr()
{
   system("cls");
}
```

save it as "ClearScreen.h" at your path of "include" folder (for ex - C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include)

compile it.

now use it in your programs like :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <ClearScreen.h>

main()
{
   clrscr();
   printf("\nHi");
   getch();
   return 0;
}
```

now compile and run it.
i hope it works....

Answer (score 1):

I just searched on the internet.

Can't remember the source, but this should be the most accurate so far.

```
#include<windows.h>    

void clear_screen ()
{
    DWORD n;                         /* Number of characters written */
    DWORD size;                      /* number of visible characters */
    COORD coord = {0};               /* Top left screen position */
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi;

    /* Get a handle to the console */
    HANDLE h = GetStdHandle ( STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE );

    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo ( h, &csbi );

    /* Find the number of characters to overwrite */
    size = csbi.dwSize.X * csbi.dwSize.Y;

    /* Overwrite the screen buffer with whitespace */
    FillConsoleOutputCharacter ( h, TEXT ( ' ' ), size, coord, &n );
    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo ( h, &csbi );
    FillConsoleOutputAttribute ( h, csbi.wAttributes, size, coord, &n );

    /* Reset the cursor to the top left position */
    SetConsoleCursorPosition ( h, coord );
}
```

**Now, all you have to do is call** `clear_screen()`

**EDIT:**

Just found the source: http://faq.cprogramming.com/cgi-bin/smartfaq.cgi?answer=1031963460&id=1043284385

Answer (score 0):

conio.h for linux

download: http://sourceforge.net/projects/conio4linux/?source=typ_redirect

copy to /usr/include

sample:

root@shu-GA-VT890P:/usr/include# ls | grep conio

:)

tested by code::blocks in ubuntu 14.10

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  system("cls");
}
```

or you can just add system("cls"); in your main function. Note: it requires stdlib.h header file , so don't forget to include it.

Comment: for very old compilers like turbo c++ , you can use `clrscr()` .

Answer (score 0):

open conio.h in  "MinGW\include"   folder just add these lines at very bottom and save conio.h

```
#include <stdlib.h>
void clrscr()
{
   system("cls");
}
```

thats all now your clrscr(); will work

Answer (score 0):

```
void function MyClearScreen()
{
 asm
    {
     mov ax,0600h;  
     mov bh,71h;    
     mov cx,0000h;  
     mov dx,184Fh;  
     int 10h;       
    };
};

int main()
{
 MyClearScreen();
}
```

Comment: A description of what the assembly does would be nice

Answer (score 0):

Try this (It is shorter than the one above):

```
#include <windows.h>

void clrscr()/*Create funcion to clean screen.*/
{
    HANDLE hStdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    COORD coord = {0, 0};
    DWORD count;
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi;
    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hStdOut, &csbi);
    FillConsoleOutputCharacter(hStdOut, ' ', csbi.dwSize.X * csbi.dwSize.Y, coord, &count);
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hStdOut, coord);
}
```

Source: [Program with clrscr funtion implemented](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1e493962-663e-404c-b951-5e9507cbb279/problems-with-switch?forum=Vsexpressvc)

Answer (score -1):

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<iostream.h>
int main()
{
//using namespace std
 clrscr();

}
```

//try this and let me know if this works

Comment: i had already done that.it doesn't work.i need an alternative for clrscr() ;